# getting file names in another php page

Tags: php

my php code for uploading files are

```
 <input type="button"  onclick="uploadFile();" value="+">

                    <input type="hidden" name="fileCount" id="fileCount" value="0" />
                    <script>

                        function uploadFile()
                        {
                            var count = parseInt($('#fileCount').val(), 10);
                            count = count + 1;
                            var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
                            var br = document.createElement("br");
                            var text = document.createElement("INPUT");
                            var remove = document.createElement("INPUT");
                            text.setAttribute("type", "text");
                            text.setAttribute("name", "description_" + count);
                            text.setAttribute("value", "file description");
                            remove.setAttribute("type", "button");
                            remove.setAttribute("value", "-");
//                          x.setAttribute("name","");
                            x.setAttribute("type", "file");
                            x.setAttribute("name", "file_" + count);
                            upload.appendChild(br);
                            upload.appendChild(x);
                            upload.appendChild(text);
                            upload.appendChild(remove);
                            $('#fileCount').val(count);
                        }
                    </script>
```

i want to get the uploaded file names in another php page so that i can insert file name to FILENAMES field of my database..could you please how to solve this?thanks.
I am using

```
 foreach ($_FILES as $files) {
            echo "<br/>";
            echo $files['name'];
        }
```

so i am getting file names.
but my real problem is how to store these names into a single variable so i can store it corresponding field

Comment: Your question is tagged `php`, but the code you posted is Javascript. Where is your PHP question?

Comment: foreach ($_FILES as $files) {
            echo "<br/>";
            echo $files['name'];
        }

Comment: If you have multiple file uploads, why do you want them in a single variable?

Comment: my databse have only one field for saving file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `implode` to combine an array into one string.

```
$names = array();
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    $names[] = $file['name'];
}
$all_names = implode(',', $names);
```